# transpose postgresql query result from rows to group by column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose

Products Table

```
INSERT INTO public."Products" ("ID", "Name", "Description") VALUES (1, 'Shirt A', 'Nice to wear');
INSERT INTO public."Products" ("ID", "Name", "Description") VALUES (2, 'Shirt B', 'Looks good');
INSERT INTO public."Products" ("ID", "Name", "Description") VALUES (3, 'Shirt C', 'Light fabric');
INSERT INTO public."Products" ("ID", "Name", "Description") VALUES (4, 'Shirt D', 'Waterproof');
```

Attributes Table

```
INSERT INTO public."Attributes" ("ProductID", "Type", "Value") VALUES (1, 'Color', 'Green');
INSERT INTO public."Attributes" ("ProductID", "Type", "Value") VALUES (1, 'Color', 'Red');
INSERT INTO public."Attributes" ("ProductID", "Type", "Value") VALUES (1, 'Size', 'M');
INSERT INTO public."Attributes" ("ProductID", "Type", "Value") VALUES (1, 'Size', 'L');
INSERT INTO public."Attributes" ("ProductID", "Type", "Value") VALUES (3, 'Color', 'Green');
INSERT INTO public."Attributes" ("ProductID", "Type", "Value") VALUES (4, 'Size', 'L');
INSERT INTO public."Attributes" ("ProductID", "Type", "Value") VALUES (4, 'Size', 'XL');
```

SQL Query combined Result needed in the following output

```
ID, NAME,   Description,   Color,        Size
1, Shirt A, Nice to wear,  [Green, Red], [M, L]
2, Shirt B, Looks good,    null,         null
3, Shirt C, Light fabric,  [Green],      null
4, Shirt D, Waterproof,    null,         [L, XL]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `join` with conditional aggregation:

```
select p.*,
       array_agg(a.value) filter (where type = 'Color') as colors,
       array_agg(a.value) filter (where type = 'Size') as sizes
from products p left join
     attributes a
     on p.id = a.productid
group by p.id;
```

Note that Postgres allows you to select all columns of a table when you aggregate by the primary key.  I assume that `id` is the primary key of `products`.

Also, don't use double quotes when defining tables.  They just clutter queries.